# Issue with ndk while compile android file

Tags: android, command-line, sdk, android-ndk, cocos2d-android

Gettting this error while compile `cocos compile -p android --ap android-25`

```
    Android NDK: Found platform level in ./project.properties. 
    Setting APP_PLATFORM to android-25.    
    Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM set to unknown platform: android-25.
```

How to avoid such error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last worked with cocos compile  -p android --android-studio because of ndk

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [Application.mk documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html) for APP_PLATFORM, it refers to [Android NDK Native APIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html), where you can find a table of NDK-supported API levels. You can find all legal values there - and 25 is not one of them. You probably need android-24.